# chromeos - failed to read partition table

Tags: arch-linux, partition, chrome-os, chrome-book

I am trying to install archlinux natively on my chromebook. I am following the instructions [here](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/samsung/samsung-chromebook), however when I try to create a new disk label for GPT

```
localhost ~ # parted /dev/mmcblk1 mklabel gpt
```

I get the following error:

```
localhost ~ # partx -t gpt -u /dev/mmcblk1
partx: /dev/mmcblk1: failed to read partition table
```

This also occurs when I try to label an USB drive. May I ask what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what does `echo /dev/mmc*` say? Your device might have the device under a different name, e.g. /dev/mmcblk0.